# how can i prevent a pwa virtual keyboard to destroy my layout? I'm using vuejs

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a pwa, in cordova app i'm using the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` associated with a cordova plugin to detect the virtual keyboard height.

but now on pwa, i'm completely lost.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm interested too.